# Zipping files in Twistd without blocking.

Tags: python, twisted

Is there a way to zip files without blocking in twisted?

```
import zipfile
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import reactor

def zip_files(file_list, path, output_Zip):
    zip_handle = zipfile.ZipFile(output_zip,  mode='w', allowZip64=True)
    try:
        for i in file_list:
            zip_handle.write(i)
        zip_handle.close()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        return False
def print_zip(res):
    print res
    return res


file_list = ['path_to_file1','path_to_file2']
output_path = 'full_path_to_output_zip'
d = defer.Deferred()
d.addCallback(lambda _: zip_files(file_list, output_path)
d.addCallback(print_zip)
zip_result = d
reactor.run()
```

I have this so far. While it does work, triggering the zipping process causes twisted to block and wait until the initial 'zip job' is finished. Id rather it terminate the existing 'zip job' and start the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, using a `DeferredList` of `deferToThread`s to not block on writing the zip files:

```
import zipfile
import logging
from twisted.internet import threads, defer
from twisted.internet import reactor

log = logging.getLogger()
log.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def zip_file(input_path, output_path):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(output_path,  mode='w', allowZip64=True) as zip_handle:
        zip_handle.write(input_path)


def log_failure(err):
    log.exception("error: %s", err)


def zip_file_and_catch_error(input_path, output_path):
    d = threads.deferToThread(zip_file, input_path, output_path)
    d.addErrback(log_failure)
    return d


def main():
    input_paths = ['path_to_file1','path_to_file2']
    output_paths = ['path_out1','path_out2']
    assert len(input_paths) == len(output_paths)
    dl = defer.DeferredList([zip_file_and_catch_error(input_path, output_path) 
                             for input_path, output_path in zip(input_paths, output_paths)])
    dl.addCallback(lambda result: log.info("result: %s", result))
    dl.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.callLater(0, reactor.stop))
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import zipfile
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor

def main():
    file_list = ['path_to_file1','path_to_file2']
    output_path = 'full_path_to_output.zip'
    zip_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(output_path, mode='w', allowZip64=True)

    d = zip_files(zip_obj, file_list)
    d.addCallback(handle_success)
    d.addErrback(handle_error)
    d.addBoth(close_zip_obj, zip_obj = zip_obj)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def zip_files(zip_obj, file_list):
    for item in file_list:
        yield zip_obj.write(item)
        # handle "interrupts" here

def handle_success(ignore):
    print('Done zipping')

def handle_error(failure):
    print('Error: {0}'.format(failure.value))

def close_zip_obj(ignore, zip_obj):
    print('Closing zip object')
    zip_obj.close()

main()
reactor.run()
```

I tried to keep my example real simple so that newcomers to Twisted won't get confused. The `ZipFile` object is created outside and passed into `zip_files()` (which is now decorated with `@inlineCallbacks` and returns a 'Deferred') this way it can be easily accessed if necessary. The success and error callbacks are handled (via `addCallback/addErrback`) update those functions to suite your needs. Finally, the `ZipFile` object, which is passed into `close_zip_obj()` from the main function, is closed once the zipping is done. This should handle lots of moderately sized files fairly quickly. For large files, you *"should"* be okay executing the task in a `deferToThread` using your original code.

However, you made a comment that is very vague:

> Id rather it terminate the existing 'zip job' and start the new one.

This assumes if you're in the middle of a zip, you want to stop the current zip and start another one. With `deferToThread`, or any threaded approach, it becomes tedious to pass flags between threads, set/unset locks, and synchronize with other threads. Just keep that in mind if you decide to use threads.